# How do I reinstall my app inside Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I need help, my app was supposed to be there but I deleted it. How do I reinstall it? I don't know how I deleted it, I just double-clicked or something.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside Android Studio"? Do you mean importing a project to AS?

Comment: Do you want to open the EMULATOR with your app?

Comment: Please add more information.